# Call a function only with first oninput use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number input field, and I want to call a function on oninput like this.

```js
function onInput(){
    $('.left-arrow' ).click(function(e) {
        $(".cancelButton").animate({
          "font-size": "1.1rem",
          "color": "#f65656"
        }, 300);
        e.preventDefault();
    });  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberInput" oninput="onInput();" type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

The `onInput();` function kicks off another function on button click. (left-arrow click)

(It animates the cancel button, but that's not important for the question)

The problem is, if I type 6 numbers it rembers al 6 function calls, zo the function wil run 6 times if I click on de (left-arrow) button. And I want the funtion only to run once if i I click on that button. What is the best way to deal with this? Or should I do this completly different?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but no. No i want to call the function when I start typing a number. so onfocus/blur is not what i want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the JQuery `one()` trigger:

```
$("#numberInput").one("input",function(){
    $('.left-arrow' ).click(function(e) {
        $(".cancelButton").animate({
          "font-size": "1.1rem",
          "color": "#f65656"
        }, 300);
        e.preventDefault();
    });  
});
```

Attaching the event only once.

**Demo Snippet:**

```js
$("#numberInput").one("input", function(){
    $("#btnOk").click(function(){
        console.log("Only once trigger per Click!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberInput">
<button id="btnOk">Click Me!</button>
```

[JQuery Source](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Thanks Matheus! I think this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I will not say that this is the best approach to do this. Instead, you can have a `flag` variable of some sort which sets to true on button click and the click handler check for this variable to be true otherwise it returns.

```
var isActivated = false;

function onInput() {
  isActivated = true;
}

$('.left-arrow').click(function(e) {
  if (!isActivated)
    return;
  $(".cancelButton").animate({
    "font-size": "1.1rem",
    "color": "#f65656"
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if there is an input everytime `.left-arrow` is clicked.

```
$('.left-arrow' ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#numberInput').val()) {
    $(".cancelButton").animate({
      "font-size": "1.1rem",
      "color": "#f65656"
    }, 300);
  }
});
```

Comment: There are already numbers (value) inside de input field. That has to stay like that. I want to call the onInput(); function when you change the number.